# How to access particular column value in android sqlite application?

Tags: android

I have an application where I want to use the values returned from an SQL query against a database in my application.  I want to use attach these values to a uri that links to a script on  remote host.  I am doing a call to the method to retrieve the values, after which I will now extract them.  The issue is that I am facing a challenge in going about this. I know a bit of php and what I want in android is done like this in php:

```
....(preceding code)...$row['email'];
```

and I can now assign a variable e.g. `$email=$row['email'];`

How can I do this in android?

I don't want a cursor returned, just the values of the columns as strings.

Below is my code (I will need help to retrieve the password column)

```
public String[] selectAll()
{
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "email","password"},null, null, null, null,null); 
    if(cursor.getCount() >0)
    {
        String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
             str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));

             i++;
         }
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        return new String[] {};
    }
}
```

I need help on inserting the "password" column so that it will be returned with the email.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
        String[][] str = new String[cursor.getCount()][cursor.getColumnCount()];

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
             for(int j=0;j<cursor.getColumnCount();j++)
                 str[i][j] = cursor.getString(j); /// may be this column start with the 1 not with the 0

             i++;
         }
```

you need to store this in two dimenstion array for row wise and column wise
but if this will give only one result everytime

```
        String[] str = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()]; // here you have pass the total column value
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
             str[0] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
             str[1] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your design like this

```
public Cursor selectAll() {    
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "email","password"},null, null, null, null,null); 
return cursor;        
    }
```

and use the selectAll function like this

```
Cursor cursor=selectAll();
String[] mail = new String[cursor.getCount()];
String[] pass = new String[cursor.getCount()];
int i=0; 
while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                 mail[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
                 pass[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));

                 i++;
             }
```